# Uncheck Checkboxes on Mozilla Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've noticed that Mozilla's refresh doesn't bring the page to a blank slate. I have checkboxes on the form that I need to be unchecked when the page is loaded/refreshed. Currently I am using this:

```
<body onLoad="uncheck()">

function uncheck() {
    // Uncheck all checkboxes on page load    
    $("input:checkbox:checked").attr("checked", "");
    console.log("uncheck");
}
```

This works for loading the page completely, but if i click refresh (in Mozilla) the function is called properly because "uncheck" is being printed to the console, but the checkboxes are remaining checked.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead:

```
$(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked',false);
```

or [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/):

```
$(':checkbox:checked').removeAttr('checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the 'page cache' by setting window onunload to anything at all-

```
window.onunload=function(){return true;};
```