# How to insert data into db using checkbox using ajax and php without form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a checkbox when checked on it i want to enter the value of the checkbox into the database.Please help me to find the Ajax and php code for this.
I tried this

```
    $(document).on('click', "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var checked = checkbox.attr('checked');
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url("contact-details-availability"); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'checkbox-select', 
            id: checkbox.attr('contact_avl'), 
            checked: checked
              },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
           // alert(data);
            // Revert
            checkbox.attr('checked', !checked);
        }
    });
});
```

and

```
public function add_contact_details_availability()
{
    if($_POST['action'] == 'checkbox-select') {
         $checkbox = $_POST['id'];
         $checked = $_POST['checked'];
        // Your MySQL code here
        echo 'Updated';
    }
           echo 'Code ran';
}
```

But it won't works

Comment: `But it won't works` which part wont work here??

Comment: Have you looked at firbug to check if sending to url?

Comment: the value doesn't pass and showing error undefined index id and checked

Comment: in ajax, `var_dump($_POST);` you ll see what all values have posted.

Comment: Try `change` event in place of `click`, one more thing replace `checked` to any other because there is one attribute with same name. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working JQuery

```
<script>
        $(document).on("change", "input[name='chk']", function () {
            var checkbox = $(this);
            var checked = checkbox.prop('checked');
            $.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo base_url("contact-details-availability"); ?>",
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    action: 'checkbox-select', 
                    id: checkbox.data('contact_avl'), 
                    checked: checked
                      },
                success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                   // alert(data);
                    // Revert
                    checkbox.attr('checked', !checked);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" data-contact_avl="val" value="1">check
```

I am saying it as **working** because all the three values are passing.
Changes done to fix are:

1] changed `var checked = checkbox.attr('checked');` to `var checked = checkbox.prop('checked');`

2] changed  `id: checkbox.attr('contact_avl')` to  id: `checkbox.data('contact_avl')`

3] changed `onclick` to `onchange`

Comment: i have one more doubt once we checked the checkbox it remains checked after refreshing the page.How it possible??

Comment: Most of the time its because browser's behavior. Read mode about it on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176155/checkbox-stays-checked-on-page-refresh and get solution for this on following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954839/uncheck-checkboxes-on-mozilla-refresh

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var id = checkbox.attr('contact_avl'),
$.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo base_url("contact-details-availability"); ?>",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'checkbox-select', 
            id: id, 
            checked: 'checked'
              },
        success: function(data) {
            //alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
           // alert(data);
            // Revert
            checkbox.attr('checked', !checked);
        }
    });
```